# PHP inside an html table using show and div

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to display some PHP generated content inside an html table, the file is a PHP file and the code I have at the moment, which is not working is:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
{
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td width="30"></td>";
echo "<td width="330" valign="top">{<div class="vpolls" id="vp_1"><div
class="vpdt"></div>Do you agree with the proposed new system of collecting Council Tax?
<form action="http://tk5solutions.com/vpoll/vpoll.php" id="vpf1" method="post"
onsubmit="return votePoll(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="idp" value="1"><label for="p1i0"><p><input type="radio"
  name="item" value="Yes" id="p1i0" />Yes</label> 
<label for="p1i1"><input type="radio"
  name="item" value="No" id="p1i1" />No</label> 
<label for="p1i2"><input type="radio"
  name="item" value="Undecided" id="p1i2" />
Undecided</label>     
<input type="submit"
  value="Vote" name="sbm" /> </p>
</form>
</div>}</td>";
echo "<td width="330" valign="top">include('vpoll/vpoll.php');
echo '<div class="vpolls">'. $obVot->showPoll(1) .'</div>';
</td>";
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work, or how to display the two sets of data (they are both in boxed frames) side by side.

Comment: Looks more like **job offer** than **asking for help**.

Comment: You need to use `'` instead of `"` in the echo... otherwise use `'` for the elements' properties...

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code modified...

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td width="30"></td>';
echo '<td width="330" valign="top">
     <div class="vpolls" id="vp_1">
     <div class="vpdt"></div>
     Do you agree with the proposed new system of collecting Council Tax?

     <form action="http://tk5solutions.com/vpoll/vpoll.php" id="vpf1" method="post"
       onsubmit="return votePoll(this);">
     <input type="hidden" name="idp" value="1" />
     <label for="p1i0"><p><input type="radio" name="item" value="Yes" id="p1i0" />Yes</label> 
     <label for="p1i1"><input type="radio" name="item" value="No" id="p1i1" />No</label> 
     <label for="p1i2"><input type="radio" name="item" value="Undecided" id="p1i2" />
      Undecided</label>     
     <input type="submit" value="Vote" name="sbm" /> </p>
     </form>
     </div></td>';

     echo '<td width="330" valign="top">';
        include('vpoll/vpoll.php');
      echo '<div class="vpolls">'. $obVot->showPoll(1) .'</div>';
     echo '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo '</table>';
?>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: You'r welcome... Please do consider above comments stating your style of asking the question. Do take it into the consideration next time... :)